# different Tick Unit (interval) in Number Axis based on density of data points in jFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart, axis

I want to show the result of my simulation with XYLineChart of JfreeChart, the range of Number Axis is between time =0 to time =3000, but the density of data points are different in different time intervals,

for example there is just few data points until time 1000, then the density in time interval (1000 - 2000 ) is too high, and again i have few data points in time interval (2000 -3000)
so, i want to have different tick unit automatically based on the density of the data points,
the only code i use is:

NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();

xAxis.setAutoRange(true);

xAxis.setAutoTickUnitSelection(true);

it must be done automatically, because, the data points are generated during my simulation, and i don't know in which interval the density is high or low

Comment: Maybe `setDomainZoomable(true)` and `setMouseWheelEnabled(true)` in `ChartPanel`?